# Filter out fields from a JsonNode

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8

I have a [Jackson](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/ObjectNode.html) `JsonNode` of sub-type `ObjectNode`:

```
ObjectNode node = parent.path('somepath');
```

`node` has a number of sub-fields, such as you'd see in this json object:

```
{
  "somepath": {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
    "c": 3,
    "d": 4
  }
}
```

So the above object `node` will have four sub-objects (all `JsonNode`/`ObjectNode`s in their own right): `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`.

Given object `node`, I'd like to filter *out* some of the subfields. For instance, let's say I'd like to filter out everything *but* some list of field names, say `["b", "c"]`. When I re-serialize the `node` object it would look like this:

```
{
  "somepath": {
    "b": 2,
    "c": 3
  }
}
```

I can think of a lot of ways where I can loop through both the field name list and the keep list, and rebuild the object, but that all seems like a lot of work and very unclear. What I'd love to use is a `Stream.filter()` type of function:

```
List<String> keepList = Lists.newArrayList("b", "c");
node.stream().filter( field -> keepList.contains(field.name()));
```

Obviously the above code doesn't work because I can't 'stream' an `ObjectNode`. Is there a way I can get this to work in a similar fashion, or am I stuck going the long way around?

Comment: Are you talking about [Jackson's `ObjectNode`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/ObjectNode.html)?

Comment: Yes. Sorry... I should have linked that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a method in `ObjectNode` that does exactly what you want: [`retain`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/ObjectNode.html#retain(java.util.Collection)). You might use it this way:

```
ObjectNode node = parent.path('somepath');

node = node.retain(keepList);
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you. I missed that - it didn't even occur to me that that method did that. Should have read the docs closer. Thank you!